# Cucumber cannot see driver when I build my project on cucumber-java(Scenario related build on feature file)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng

testng.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="All Test Suite">
    <test verbose="2" preserve-order="true" 
    name="C:/Users/onur.tarar/IdeaProjects/CucumberSample">
     <classes>
      <class name ="Runner"></class>
     </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

This is my runner file:

```
 import driver.DriverInit;
    import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
    import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
    import utils.CucumberUtils;
    import utils.Helper;
           import java.io.File;
           import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
           import java.io.IOException;
           @CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/java/features"},
           glue = {"steps"},
           monochrome = true,
           plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber.json", 
     "html:target/site/cucumber-report.html"})
           public class Runner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

           @BeforeSuite
           public void deleteFile() throws IOException {
           DriverInit driverInit = new DriverInit();
           driverInit.initialize();

           }
           }


           @AfterSuite
           public void afterSuite() throws FileNotFoundException {
           DriverInit.webDriver.quit();
           }
```

Error log:

...

```
Step failed java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.navigate()" because "pages.HomePage.webDriver" is null
```

...

**

When I used Junit before I had to initialize webdriver in steps package to solution. I cannot do that with testng because if I tried this way then I cannot use mvn test command. **

I also use @FindBy for keeping the web elements, so if you're using @FindBy you have initialize your webdriver @BeforeSuite otherwise your all web elements getting null exception

Thank you for all answers already

Comment: Hello, can you share your steps class so I can take a look. I think the issue is in there.